# Drawing an I-Beam based on two points

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I have two Point structures and I need to draw an I-Beam based on those points, where each point represents the cross-section on either side of the I-Beam.  The width of the end caps should be fixed and arbitrary.

Basically I need to draw three lines.  First I'll DrawLine(Point1, Point2), then I need the math to figure out how to draw the next two lines on perpendicular angles so that they are centered on Point1 and Point2.

The image below shows what I need to draw based on the center line.  However, this line can be at any angle.  The Point1 and Point2 that connect the line can be anywhere in a 2D space.

[image: Example of an I-Beam]

Comment: Please describe your problem in a way that people unfamiliar with what you are trying to do can understand it.

Comment: An I-Beam, like the letter I.  See http://bit.ly/odjXNT.  Or google image search for I-Beam.  I have the middle line already (drawn from two points, one at each end).  I need to draw the other two lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try playing around with LineCaps:

```
protected void DrawIBeam(Graphics g, Point fromPoint, Point toPoint)
{
  using (GraphicsPath hPath = new GraphicsPath())
  {
    hPath.AddLine(new Point(-5, 0), new Point(5, 0));
    CustomLineCap myCap = new CustomLineCap(null, hPath);
    myCap.SetStrokeCaps(LineCap.Round, LineCap.Round);
    using (Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
    {
      myPen.CustomStartCap = myCap;
      myPen.CustomEndCap = myCap;
      g.DrawLine(myPen, fromPoint, toPoint);
    }
  }
}
```

and call it:

```
DrawIBeam(e.Graphics, new Point(10, 10), new Point(60, 60));
```

[image]

From [CustomLineCap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.customlinecap.aspx)

Comment: This worked awesome, and very customizable.  Thanks!  This solution is the best since I don't need to re-invent the wheel and can let the GDI calculate the math.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a width that's half the width of the I part of the I beam, first you find the slope of the first line you drew.

Next, you take the negative inverse of the slope, and draw a line from Point1 of length width in both directions.  That's why width is half of the width you want to draw.

Finally you draw a line from Point 2 of length width in both directions.

Here's the mathematical formula for [drawing a perpendicular line](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordperpendicular.html).

Comment: I was trying this, but I wasn't so much as looking for the mathematical functions as I was looking to translate those functions into real code.  For example, using those formulas I was getting divide-by-zero errors sometimes, which I didn't know how to deal with.

Comment: @Moozhe: True.  If the slope of the line from Point1 to Point2 is zero, the inverse slope will be infinity.  That's a special case (line horizontal, I parts vertical as well as line vertical, I parts horizontal) that you'll have to handle without taking the negative inverse slope.